# Ruby on Rails: Capturing JSON data from webhook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webhooks

I'm trying to understand how webhook works. My understanding is that its the ability to connect two different applications. If I submit a webhook with url

> localhost:3000/receiver

to one application, and I have my application with a method

```
def receiver

end
```

I was wondering if I don't know what the callback is from the webhook would be, how would I capture data? How do I save any JSON data thats communicating with my application? I was thinking maybe save some file to see what the objects are, but I'm still fairly new and not sure how to capture JSON data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that the webhook is returning a JSON, you can so something like this

```
data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read
```

Comment: Added benefit of using this as well is it gets around incoming params that are named the same as ones that rails uses. For example `params[:action]`. If there is a incoming param called `:action` it will get overwritten by rails

Answer (score 2):

1. Sure, a webhook a is tool to sincronize two apps
2. You HAVE tou know the structure of the incoming json, because you need to get the info inside
3. By definition a webhook is sent by POST method, so you can capture it just inspecting the body of the petition, i.e.

   ```
   webHook = JSON.parse(params[:something])
   ```

Your would try with github web hooks and publish your app in heroku, the api is very well documented and there are many examples.

Comment: I'd like to know how to capture any value instead of finding the params. What if I don't know what the parameters are?

Comment: You can inspect the values in a each method, but you as a good practice, in order to map the values to a db have to know the structure of the params, take a look at the provider api, it will show you the structure of the messages, ie http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/